# pandas: add week dates with dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, date

I have a df like, which has such rows:

```
    p_id    m_id    x_id    g_id    u_id
0   2       NaN     1408    7       121
1   3       1259    117     23      315
2   3       1259    221     9       718
3   3       1259    397     76      367
```

and two datetime objects:

start_date:

```
datetime.datetime(2021, 5, 25, 0, 0)
```

end_date:

```
datetime.datetime(2021, 5, 29, 0, 0)
```

how do I get a df like, basically (adding the week-dates from start_date to end_date with each row):

```
    p_id    m_id    x_id    g_id    u_id  s_date
0   2       NaN     1408    7       121   2021-05-25
1   2       NaN     1408    7       121   2021-05-26
2   2       NaN     1408    7       121   2021-05-27
3   2       NaN     1408    7       121   2021-05-28
4   2       NaN     1408    7       121   2021-05-29

5   3       1259    117     23      315   2021-05-25
6   3       1259    117     23      315   2021-05-26
7   3       1259    117     23      315   2021-05-27
8   3       1259    117     23      315   2021-05-28
9   3       1259    117     23      315   2021-05-29
.
.
15  3       1259    397     76      367   2021-05-25
16  3       1259    397     76      367   2021-05-26
17  3       1259    397     76      367   2021-05-27
18  3       1259    397     76      367   2021-05-28
19  3       1259    397     76      367   2021-05-29
```

Answer (score 5):

#### Generate [`date_range`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html) and cross [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge.html)

1. In pandas version >= `1.2x`, to perform a cross merge we can now pass an optional parameter `how='cross'` to the merge function

```py
dates = pd.date_range(start_date, end_date)
df.merge(dates.to_series(name='s_date'), how='cross')
```

2. For pandas version < `1.2x` we have to create a temporary merge key in order to perform the `cross` merge

```py
dates = pd.date_range(start_date, end_date)
df.assign(k=1).merge(dates.to_frame(name='s_date').assign(k=1), on='k').drop('k', 1)
```

---

```
    p_id    m_id  x_id  g_id  u_id     s_date
0      2     NaN  1408     7   121 2021-05-25
1      2     NaN  1408     7   121 2021-05-26
2      2     NaN  1408     7   121 2021-05-27
3      2     NaN  1408     7   121 2021-05-28
4      2     NaN  1408     7   121 2021-05-29
5      3  1259.0   117    23   315 2021-05-25
6      3  1259.0   117    23   315 2021-05-26
7      3  1259.0   117    23   315 2021-05-27
8      3  1259.0   117    23   315 2021-05-28
9      3  1259.0   117    23   315 2021-05-29
10     3  1259.0   221     9   718 2021-05-25
11     3  1259.0   221     9   718 2021-05-26
12     3  1259.0   221     9   718 2021-05-27
13     3  1259.0   221     9   718 2021-05-28
14     3  1259.0   221     9   718 2021-05-29
15     3  1259.0   397    76   367 2021-05-25
16     3  1259.0   397    76   367 2021-05-26
17     3  1259.0   397    76   367 2021-05-27
18     3  1259.0   397    76   367 2021-05-28
19     3  1259.0   397    76   367 2021-05-29
```

Answer (score 2):

The way I would do is to first create a list of all the dates between the two dates and add this as a new column to the dataframe and then use `explode` to explode into rows:

Here is an example:

```
df['s_date'] = [pd.date_range(datetime(2021, 5, 25, 0, 0),datetime(2021, 5, 29, 0, 0),freq='d')] * len(df)
df = df.explode('s_date')
```

Output:

```
    id  start   score   date
0   id1     NaN     3   2021-05-25
0   id1     NaN     3   2021-05-26
0   id1     NaN     3   2021-05-27
0   id1     NaN     3   2021-05-28
0   id1     NaN     3   2021-05-29
1   id2     12.0    1   2021-05-25
1   id2     12.0    1   2021-05-26
1   id2     12.0    1   2021-05-27
1   id2     12.0    1   2021-05-28
1   id2     12.0    1   2021-05-29
2   id3     11.0    8   2021-05-25
2   id3     11.0    8   2021-05-26
2   id3     11.0    8   2021-05-27
2   id3     11.0    8   2021-05-28
2   id3     11.0    8   2021-05-29
...
...
```

Answer (score 1):

the steps in my solution:

1. create a list of all the dates
2. convert the list into `DataFrame`
3. add 'key' column for merge
4. `pd.merge` the two `DataFrame` (outer join)
5. remove 'key' column

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
# example to your df
a = [{'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'a': 3, 'b': 4}]
a_df = pd.DataFrame(a)

start_date = datetime.strptime('2021-05-01', '%Y-%m-%d')
end_date = datetime.strptime('2021-06-01', '%Y-%m-%d')
num_of_days = (end_date - start_date).days

date_df = pd.DataFrame([start_date + timedelta(days=x) for x in range(num_of_days)], columns=['date'])
a_df = pd.DataFrame(a)

a_df['key'] = 0
date_df['key'] = 0

a_df = a_df.merge(date_df, on='key', how='outer')
a_df = a_df.drop('key', 1)

a_df
```